# How to change the version of android application

Tags: android

my main class :-

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Splash extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    }

}
```

manifeast:-

```
package="aaa.amit.com"
    android:versionCode="1"//that i have change android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.0" >//android:versionName="1.0.1"

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"

        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

Can anyone tell me how I can change my version?

Comment: i want to change the version of my app ........ this code is for example only my app are in Google play store ....

Comment: increment `versionCode` and `versionName` in manifest file.

Comment: Which version are U talking  about .. Please specify more

Comment: i want to change my new version   android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.0.1" >

Comment: equally i want to update my application apk file and re upload on google play store so then can u tell me friends

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change android version and code version number in Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22274657/how-to-change-android-version-and-code-version-number-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just try changing .. in your manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.androidhacker.googlemapsv2"
    android:versionCode="2" <!-- 1 / 2 / 3 etc for version code @Thanks laalto ..-->
    android:versionName="1.1" > <!-- 1.1 / 1.2 etc for version name ..-->
```

Update:: Exporting project ..

```
(1) Right click on project.
(2) Select Export.
(3) Now check option for android -> Export Android Application.
(4) Check your project name and click next.
(5)Now select option "Use existing keystore" and browse where you need to keep .apk file. Put password which was used for creating first built. click next and fallow other.

Now you can find your new .apk file at place where you located at point-5.
```

That's it. you are done with your work.

Comment: I have change the version code="2"<??????what should there?????????> android:version="1.0.1" <????? what should be there ???????>                                                     so there what is the need of certificate fingerprints.....can there need of finger prints or not.......

Comment: I hope you are updating your app on Google play. so each time you require to create .apk file from scratch means you need to export whole project again. Let me know if any concerns

Comment: yes i have need to open my project i have finger prints in other places now i want to update my apk that particular file ....so can u tell me

Comment: heeee thank androidHacker this is very great satisfaction answer for me thank  u D

Comment: this is Currect Answer for any Fresher Developer

Comment: [update]anyone change or update this question : Version change option/edit  not in `Manifest file` . Now it is in `build.gradle(Module:myApp)`

Answer (score 9):

Which version do you want to change?
If it's to update your app on the store, you must increment the `android:versionCode="1"`. Which will not be visible for users.

If you want to show users that you incremented your app's version, you can increment aswell the `android:versionName="1.0"`, just keep in mind that increment the versionCode is mandatory to update your app on the store.

Comment: i have change that kind of activity before that i know i should change the things which u have tell me ...........but i want to know the think there are any need of fingerprints "MD5" or "SHA1"

Answer (score 5):

In android Studio add/change versionCode and versionName :

```
       versionCode 0
       versionName "0.0.2"
```

not just in manifest but most importnant inside build.gradle file:: defaultConfig{ } of your module:
Like that:

build.gradle(Module:myApp)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xyz.mypackage"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 0
        versionName "0.0.1"
     }
     buildTypes {
         release {
             minifyEnabled false
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
          }
        }
     }

  dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
   }
```

Bear in mind that build.gradle is "stronger" then the manifest. Meaning if you have these lines

```
       versionCode 0
       versionName "0.0.2"
```

inside 
build.gradle then the same lines in manifest will have no influence . 
If you want to update the version from manifest - then remove this lines 
from the build.gradle.

Answer (score 1):

correct answer is already given in Question

```
package="aaa.amit.com"
android:versionCode="2"
```

//that i have change android:versionCode="2" it is depends on user

```
android:versionName="1.0.2" >
```

//this is for android version of apk 2 which will make updated apk if in future you want to upgrade apk then just have need to increment this number of version like 2 to 3 if user want  to change version then "1.0.2" to "1.0.3" version change

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"

    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the following:

```
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
```

`versionCode` is used by the Google Play to verifiy which version of your app is newer. `versionName` is the name which is displayed in the application manager on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Just press ctrl+shift+alt+S to open the Property structure dialog.
click 'app' and click the 'Flavors' tab.
enter the version code and and number

This automatically changes the the version code in gradle.build file
 hope this helps someone.