# How to change Android version and code version number?

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

How to change Android version and code version number Android Studio? I want to change apk file (app) on Google Play and I need to change Android version and code version number. I tried with this in AndroidManifest.xml file in Android Studio:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.bestsoftcorporation.circle.app"
android:versionCode="101"
android:versionName="2.0">
```

But it does not work. When I tried to publish it on Google Play it display that I must to change Android version name and code.

Answer (score 436, accepted):

Go in the **build.gradle** and set the version code and name inside the `defaultConfig` element

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is there a way to access the versionname in Java?

Comment: Do we also have to change the xml verion if only java files have been updated ?-> ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: Make sure to clean the project after changing the version or it may not show up in the APK.

Comment: It solved my issue too. However, I really really hate,hate,hhhaaate when you have million different places where to change a variable and just one of them is the right one, like in this case!!!!

Comment: Just to mention that my project (Imported from Eclipse) didn't have the relevent lines in the build.gradle. Using the method below suggested by Ivo Stoyanov worked and added the lines.

Comment: It's pretty annoying, since this setting was just for a single App, why not keep it in APP's manifest.xml ?  Google did this for no reason......

Comment: @RRTW True mate, it's fricking annoying to scrape Documentation when this one line is all it takes ...

Comment: Make sure you edit the `versionCode` and the `versionName` of this file: `platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` intead of `platforms/android/build.gradle` where you cannot find the `versionCode` and the `versionName`.

Answer (score 93):

The easiest way to set the version in Android Studio:

**1. Press** <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> **(or File -> Project Structure)**

*Android Studio < 3.4:*

2. Choose app (from left panel).
3. Choose tab 'Flavors'
4. The last two fields are 'Version Code' and 'Version Name'

*Android Studio >= 3.4:*

2. Choose 'Modules' in the left panel.
3. Choose 'app' in middle panel.
4. Choose 'Default Config' tab in the right panel.
5. Scroll down to see and edit 'Version Code' and 'Version Name' fields.

Comment: FYI: File -> Project Structure -> Choose tab 'Flavors'
Thank you @Ivo Stoyanov

Comment: I face very strange issue. I change versionName from build.gradle file but it was not updated in BuildConfig file and so when I generate apk, it shows wrong versionName. Then I edit versionName from flavors, then it starts working. Thank you!

Comment: Note: This no longer works as of Android Studio 3.4

Answer (score 24):

You can define your `versionName` and `versionCode` in your module's `build.gradle` file like this :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    .... //Other Configuration
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> in android studio or go to File > Project Structure...

Select app on left side and select Flavors tab on right side on default config change version code, name and etc...
[image]

Comment: Unable to find app option after generating my signed apk

Answer (score 5):

You can **manage your application versioning wisely** by using the **[Advanced Build Version Plugin](https://github.com/moallemi/gradle-advanced-build-version)** for Gradle.

You just need to include the plugin in yout `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
      jcenter()
  }

  dependencies {
      classpath 'org.moallemi.gradle.advanced-build-version:gradle-plugin:1.5.0'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'org.moallemi.advanced-build-version'
```

And then you can use the versioning functions (and, obviously, **customize** them):

```
advancedVersioning {
    nameOptions { }
    codeOptions { }
    outputOptions { }
}

def appVersionName = advancedVersioning.versionName
def appVersionCode = advancedVersioning.versionCode
```

For more information, take a look at the [official documentation](https://github.com/moallemi/gradle-advanced-build-version/blob/master/README.md).

Answer (score 4):

The official documentation on this is [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning).

The short answer is do it in Gradle not the manifest, Gradle overwrites the manifest.

The `File | Project Structure | Modules | Default Config` answer given above just updates Gradle via a UI rather than by directly editing XML.

[image: How to update the Gradle XML]

The longer answer is:

> If your app defines the app version directly in the  element, the version values in the Gradle build file will override the settings in the manifest. Additionally, defining these settings in the Gradle build files allows you to specify different values for different versions of your app. For greater flexibility and to avoid potential overwriting when the manifest is merged, you should remove these attributes from the  element and define your version settings in the Gradle build files instead.

Answer (score 3):

Open your build.gradle file and make sure you have `versionCode` and `versionName` inside `defaultConfig` element. If not, add them. Refer to [this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Manifest-entries) link for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Go in the build.gradle and set the version code and name inside the defaultConfig element

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

Answer (score 1):

After updating the manifest file, instead of building your project, go to command line and reach the path ...bld\Debug\platforms\android. Run the command "ant release". Your new release.apk file will have a new version code.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get the other answers to work in Android Studio 1.4. But this worked:
click on your app name to the left below the main ribbon.
It will show a list of files.
Open `AndroidManifest.xml` and change the version code and version number there.

Answer (score 1):

Android version and code version number change on Android Studio >= 3.6:

Two ways to achieve this:

1. Direct on the Android project by Open Flutter project and modify the file

   local.properties

change the following values.  Example:

```
flutter.buildMode=release
flutter.versionName=3.0.0
flutter.sdk=C\:\\src\\flutter
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\vgonza\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk
flutter.versionCode=30
```

2. Open pubspec.yaml

Change the

```
version: 2.0.0+8
```

Meaning: 
The version name is 2.0.0
The version code is 8

See example by Suragch in:

[How to set build and version number of Flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54357468/how-to-set-build-and-version-number-of-flutter-app)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily auto increase versionName and versionCode programmatically.

For Android add this to your gradle script and also create a file version.properties with VERSION_CODE=555

```
android {
        compileSdkVersion 30
        buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
    
        def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')
        if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
            def Properties versionProps = new Properties()
    
            versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))
    
            def code = versionProps['VERSION_CODE'].toInteger() + 1
    
            versionProps['VERSION_CODE'] = code.toString()
            versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)
    
    
            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "app.umanusorn.playground"
                minSdkVersion 29
                targetSdkVersion 30
                versionCode code
                versionName code.toString()
```

Comment: mention any reference

Answer (score 0):

To change version of your app you have to change both of versionCode and versionName in the following files:

build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pms.app"
        minSdk 30
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0.5-beta"
    }
```

app_config.json:

```
{
  "minSdkVersion": 21.0,
  "viewBindingEnabled": false,
............
  "useR8": false,
  "targetSdkVersion": 30.0,
  "versionName": "1.0.5-beta",
  "versionCode": 2.0,
  "zipAlignEnabled": false
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pms.app"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.0.5-beta">
```

Answer (score 0):

## If you are using Flutter

Go to pubspec.yaml and find
`version: 0.9.04+4`

The left part of the + is the version name, the right part is the version code. This will edit the `local.properties` file (inside Android folder) and set the respective versionName and versionCode