# Unwanted versioncode increment in android Manifest

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to deploy a version 1.1 update to my android apk of my worklight app. However when I try to update the versionName on my Manifest and build the project, it automatically gets updated back to 1.0 (updated to 1.1) and versionCode is also auto incremented. I do not want this to happen and I want an updated version 1.1 to be built. Any help here please ?
example entry below... the versionCode got updated to 13 from 12.
    android:versionCode="13" android:versionName="1.0"

I use eclipse/worklight and not Android Studio. This auto update is still kind of confusing me.

Comment: Here goes your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22274657/how-to-change-android-version-and-code-version-number-in-android-studio

Comment: @Avi Version of apk can not update you should update it from manifesto file

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Android Studio settings in your app `build.gradle` will override your app manifest.

Make your changes in `build.gradle` file

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.abc.yourapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.1"
}
```

Comment: Sorry guys. I use eclipse/worklight and not Android Studio. This auto update is still kind of confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to change version

[here is link](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html)

if it is not working for you then clean project and then rebuild it

Comment: Manifest.xml is not a webservice or not a link update you should write it programmatic change it .in then make build or apk.