# How can I auto-increment build number on Flutter App?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

Currently every time I build my APK I manually need to update my build version in 2 places - which seems very unautomated and counter-intuitive (I am comparing this to the Jenkins BUILD_ID).

I understand that I must (and prefer it so) manually update the (semver) version - 0.2.0.

But surely there must be some kind of process/setting/plugin that can automatically update the +3 on every build?  I have read a lot of posts and solutions, but none actually do what I would expect it to do (I don't really want pre-build hooks and perl regex scripts unless I have to).

Note: I am not yet pushing to PlayStore - just distributing APK to core team.

**pubspec.yaml**

```yaml
version: 0.2.0+3
```

and

**local.properties**

```
flutter.versionName=0.2.0
flutter.versionCode=3
```

I am using :

- Android Studio 4.0.2
- Flutter 1.22

Answer (score 5):

What I do is use a shell script that sets the build number in `pubspec.yaml` based on the `git commit` count and an offset. The offset is used when I need to increment a build without changing the commit, such as when publishing the same version to Beta and Prod.

Using VSCode on my Mac, I've also setup a Launch and Task to execute the script prior to each build, but it can also be run manually or converted to a Windows BAT file (with the appropriate Linux tools `awk` `sed` `grep` `wc` `xargs` installed.

Note that you need to stop and re-run (rebuild) the iOS and Android projects before they'll recognize the updated builder number.

I run this in the folder above the Flutter project:

```
#!/bin/bash

path_to_pubspec="flutter_project/pubspec.yaml"
current_version=$(awk '/^version:/ {print $2}' $path_to_pubspec)
current_version_without_build=$(echo "$current_version" | sed 's/\+.*//')
revisionoffset=0
gitcount=`git log | grep "^commit" | wc -l | xargs`
new_version="$current_version_without_build+$gitcount"
echo "Setting pubspec.yaml version $current_version to $new_version"
sed -i "" "s/version: $current_version/version: $new_version/g" $path_to_pubspec
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been wondering the same thing since it causes issues when uploading to the app stores.

Looks like the solution is to automate this process with something like fastlane, which is what the Flutter docs seem to favor.

Fastlane: https://fastlane.tools/

Flutter docs on Continuous Delivery: https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/cd

Fastlane `increment_build_number` action: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/increment_build_number/

Comment: More useful discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54357468/how-to-set-build-and-version-number-of-flutter-app

Comment: increment_build_number only works for iOS

Comment: Supported platforms are iOS and Mac. Here's a link to the source https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/increment_build_number/#:~:text=increment_build_number-,Supported%20platforms,-ios%2C%20mac

Answer (score 1):

My project development environment is as follows:

- OS: macOS
- IDE: IntelliJ IDEA

Here is my solution:

1. Create a `Shell Script Configuration` in `Run/Debug Configurations`:

   - Name: update_build_number
   - Execute: ◉ Script text
   - Script text:

     ```
     sed -i '' -E "s/(version: [0-9.]+\+)[0-9]+/\1$(git rev-list --count HEAD)/" pubspec.yaml
     ```
   - ☑︎ Execute in the terminal
2. Edit the Flutter script `main.dart` in the project and add `update_build_number` under `Before launch`:

   Run/Debug Configurations → Flutter → main.dart → Before launch → + Run Another Configuration → ☑︎ update_build_number

This way, every time you run or debug `main.dart`, the application's `build number` will be updated based on the commit count.

Comment: thank you for this - i will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

What works for me:

1. Open your `app/build.gradle` file.
2. Set `versionCode` to `1` (if it is `flutterVersionCode.toInteger()`)

   ```
   android {
       ...
       defaultConfig {
         ...
         versionCode 1
         versionName flutterVersionName
       }
   }
   ```
3. Run this command - `fastlane add_plugin increment_version_code`
4. Open `fastlane/Fastfile` and add this lane

   ```
   lane :increment_build_num do
       previous_build_number = google_play_track_version_codes(
         package_name: 'Package name',
         track: "internal",
         json_key: "Json key path",
       )[0]

       current_build_number = previous_build_number + 1

       increment_version_code(
         gradle_file_path: "./app/build.gradle",
         version_code: current_build_number
       )
    end
   ```
5. Run `fastlane increment_build_num` before making a new build

Comment: thank you. i will try this out sometime over the weekend

Comment: It would be nice to have some feedback. Thank you @batman567