# Flutter and Automatic Versioning

Tags: flutter, semantic-versioning, conventional-commits

I was wondering whether is it possible to have automatic versioning (following the [SemVer](https://semver.org/) convention) in Flutter, set in a GitLab/GitHub/BitBucket pipeline.
Obviously, all git commits will follow the [Conventional Commits](https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0/) structure.

I searched a lot but could not find anything helpful. All I could find was a way to create automatic changelog based on the commits (but that is not my situation here).
Has anyone encountered the same problem and found a solution?

Comment: Checkout this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64571298/how-can-i-auto-increment-build-number-on-flutter-app

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's definitely possible.

### Step 1: Add Version Plugin

Add the `version` plugin to your `pubspec.yaml` file under the `dev_dependencies` section:

```
dev_dependencies:
version: ^2.0.0
```

The `version` plugin provides a way to manage the version number of your application and generate version-related code.

### Step 2: Configure Version Plugin

Create a new file named `version.dart` in the `lib/` directory of your project, and add the following code to it:

```
import 'package:version/version.dart';

final version = Version(0, 1, 0);
```

This creates a `version` variable with an initial version number of `0.1.0`. This version number will be automatically incremented based on the commits following the Conventional Commits structure.

### Step 3: Configure GitLab Pipeline

Create a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file in the root directory of your project and add the following code to it:

```
stages:
  - build
  - release

flutter_build:
  stage: build
  image: cirrusci/flutter:stable
  script:
    - flutter packages get
    - flutter build apk
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk

release:
  stage: release
  image: cirrusci/flutter:stable
  script:
    - flutter packages get
    - flutter pub get
    - version patch
    - git add pubspec.yaml lib/version.dart
    - git commit -m "Bump version to \${CI_COMMIT_TAG}"
    - git tag -a "\${CI_COMMIT_TAG}" -m "Version \${CI_COMMIT_TAG}"
    - git push origin "\${CI_COMMIT_TAG}"
```

This pipeline consists of two stages: `build` and `release`. In the `build` stage, we build the Flutter APK and save it as an artifact. In the `release` stage, we increment the version number using the `version patch` command, commit the changes to the `pubspec.yaml` and `lib/version.dart` files, and tag the commit with the new version number. Finally, we push the tag to the remote Git repository.

### Step 4: Configure GitLab Environment Variables

In order to use the `version` plugin, we need to set up two environment variables in the GitLab pipeline:

- `FLUTTER_ROOT`: the path to the Flutter SDK
- `PUB_CACHE`: the path to the pub cache directory

Add the following environment variables to your GitLab project:

- `FLUTTER_ROOT`: `/opt/flutter`
- `PUB_CACHE`: `$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.pub-cache`

### Step 5: Create a New Release

To create a new release, follow these steps:

Push a commit following the Conventional Commits structure. For example:

```
feat: add new feature
```

Create a new tag with the `v` prefix and the new version number. For example:

```
git tag -a v0.1.1 -m "Version 0.1.1"
```

Push the tag to the remote Git repository:

```
git push origin v0.1.1
```

The GitLab pipeline will automatically trigger the `release` stage and increment the version number in the `version.dart` file, commit the changes, and tag the commit with the new version number.

The new release APK will be available as an artifact in the GitLab pipeline, under the `build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/` directory.

Comment: I am getting the following error: `bash: version: command not found`.
What should I do?

Comment: Also, I think this tutorial is not right, since I wanted to increment the version in the `pubspec.yaml` file, not in another one

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can by integrating **Fastlane** in your project

link : https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/cd#fastlane