# Version code 1 has already been used. Try another version code

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, google-play-console

I am uploading new app bundle to play console and it is saying after uploading `Version code 1 has already been used. Try another version code.`

I have changed version number in pubspec.yaml from version number: 1.0.0+1 to 2.0.0+1 even though it is saying the same error

Comment: In my case, I have an updated version but the upload wasn't successful, So the version was uploaded but not added to the release. when I tried to re-upload it, I got that error.

the solution in that case is selecting it from the library (no need to generate a new version)!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

For Flutter only:
Goto `Pubspec.yaml` file and find `version` key and Change the value after the + sign.

For Example:
In your pubspec.yaml file, if your version is like this `version: 1.0.0+1` then change it to `version: 1.0.0+2`

Comment: No, it isn't!... You don't even have to put a number after the plus sign of you don't want to! You can just put "1.0.1" for example.

Comment: @Karolina Hagegård, not true. I got the error when I put "1.0.1" and my previous release was "1.0.0" without the plus sign. Putting "1.0.1+2" for the new release was accepted and the error disappears.

Comment: Not for me... But I believe now this has something to do with the `build.gradle` files over-writing some of the values from the `pubspec.yaml` file, depending on settings... I removed an "if" statement for over-writing null value in one of my `build.gradle` files and it solved my problem. 

Comment: Indeed!! I'm uploading my first app and after solving some complaint and re uploading the corrected bundle I got the error..tried increasing to `1.0.1+1` but it worked only when increased the `+1` to `1.0.0.0+2`, no other change would work. Many thanks

Comment: In 1.0.0+1, the value before + translates to Version Code and the value after + translates to Version Name. You could use 1.0.1+alpha or 1.0.1+beta etc. On Google Play, each successive Version Code should be higher than previous one and each Version Name needs to be different (can be alpha-numeric).

Answer (score 159):

You have two ways to solve this, if you released your bundle already, then you have to update your version code like in [balu k's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69822849/5501940),

If you're still developing and pushing an app bundle for say, testing, and then you delete it, this bundle is **saved as a draft with that version code**. Therefore, it says that you can't use the same version because it already sees another one with the same version name.

Here's how you fix  it:

1. Go to the release section
2. go to app bundle explorer, in the top right you should see a dropdown button for you app version, click on it.
3. A bottomsheet containing all the previous app bundles you uploaded will show. Delete the one with the clashing bundle version and you're good to go.

Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: This is not a maintainable solution.

Comment: @Len_X this solution is only for pre-releasing, if you release your app, then your solution is the right way

Comment: Thanks for the 2nd option (app bundle explorer). I had created a release and it was denying my upload. Didn't want to increment +1 to keep iOS version paired.

Comment: I can't see the "delete" option when I click on the dropdown, next to app version. Does it still work?

Comment: This is what I was looking for as I had to update the bundle before publishing it.

Comment: Even when you pre-release, you can increment the version code number! It's not the same as the version name, after all. I just published my blackbox version 1.0.0 with the version code 18.  The user sees only "1.0.0". The "18" is only for Play Store.

Comment: @MichaelSoliman how to delete the app bundle in the bottomsheet? (step 3) , I can't find delete button/icon on the bottom sheet like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFK0L.png

Comment: FYI I was testing around and uploaded four app bundles for closed testing. Not sure why only the release 4 and 2 can be deleted. The "Delete app bundle" button does not show up for release 1 and 3.

Comment: The bundle I was trying to delete was used in a draft release and I couldn't find the delete bundle button. After I deleted the release, the delete bundle button appeared. :)

Comment: Perhaps its changed over the years, but what does the dropdown look like?

Comment: GOTO -> App Bundle Explorer. Scroll down. There you will find the builds. Select it. You will find "Delete" button in the bundle details page.

Comment: If you cant find App Bundle Explorer, just google it, and it will land you on a proper page in the Play Store.

Answer (score 96):

You can do it manually by going to "app_name/android/app/build.gradle" file. In defaultConfig section change version code to a higher number

```
  defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.app"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1 // Change to a higher number
        versionName "1.0.1" // Change to a higher number
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I have the versionCode set to `40000` and version Name set to `"4.0"` in my build.gradle, and the app bundle still gets 1/"1.0"

Comment: For those who are using Expo and EAS with a managed app and don't have access to the Android folder: add the "versionCode" key in your app.json file, inside the "android" key.

Comment: more details can be found in the expo docs about "versionCode" https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/app-versions/

Answer (score 40):

First go to the `app/build.gradle`

[image]

change `versionCode` and `versionName` like this (+1)

[image]

I think this will be helpful for someone ✌

Comment: Super confusing to keep track of.

Comment: However, this is just "default configurations"... Doesn't all the other code in the `android/app/build.gradle` file sometimes over-write the default values? Or this over-writes the other code?... In any case, feels like there is some proper way to do it, that we haven't yet figured out. 

Comment: This worked for me. It should be set as "Correct answer".

Answer (score 21):

You have to increment the `+1`, it should be `+2` to indicate build number

Comment: Shouldn't the build number be "scoped" from within the version number? `1.0.0+1` and `2.0.0+1` are obviously not the same version...

Comment: @OshMansor, by OP do you mean Len_X or balu k? Changing the version from `1.0.0+1` to `1.0.0+2` _or_ `2.0.0+1` should avoid the issue. Or are we saying that's not the case? If you increment the major version number, do you also need to increment the revision number? That is, `1.0.0+1` to `2.0.0+1` won't solve this issue, but `1.0.0+1` to `2.0.0+2` will?

Comment: @BrandonEssler OP=Len_X. And yes only your latter case would work i.e. `1.0.0+1` to `2.0.0+2`. I tried the former and it still would not let me pass the submission.

Comment: It's so confusing to delete the existing aab, I just couldn't and now the worst has happened, my apple version is 1.0.1 whereas my android is on 3.0.0(3)....

Answer (score 13):

if you remove apk then upload same version apk so you get Error **Version code 1 has already been used. Try another version code** in this situation you should remove version from **App bundle explorer** then upload same version apk.

Comment: This is the simplest way if you are not ready to increment the version number in your bundle.  It worked for me!

Comment: However, there is a point with version code numbers!  If you do it this way, you're missing that point.

Comment: unable to find remove button in app bundle explorer

Comment: If you cancelled accidently or if you get any error while uploading bundle then must try this solution.

**This should be a accepted answer**.

Answer (score 9):

If you're running into app bundle approval issues inside of the Google Play store with an Expo/React Native project, here are some tips:

1. Google Play versioning is actually checking your `AndroidManifest.xml` file for versioning (`/android/app/src/`). This should get updated from Expo's `app.json` file (`/app.json`) during build, [per their instructions](https://docs.expo.dev/distribution/building-standalone-apps).

`app.json` example section, where I've bumped my app up to a `v2.0` - note the `versionCode` inside of the Android settings object AND the `version` at the settings object root both need to be adjusted:

```
{
  "name": "app-name",
  "displayName": "App Name",
  "expo": {
    "android": {
      "package": "app.here",
      "permissions": [],
      "versionCode": 2
    }
  },
  "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

2. If your Android version isn't updating (possibly if you have a detached Expo app), you have to go directly into the `AndroidManifest.xml` file and make the modification there (`/android/app/src/`):

Example of `AndroidManifest.xml` (note your modifications happen on the `<manifest>` tag, using the `android:versionCode` and `android:versionName`:

```
<manifest 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  package="com.aganashapp"
  android:versionCode="2"
  android:versionName="2.0"
>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
  >
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATE_URL" android:value="https://exp.host/@username/app-name" />
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_SDK_VERSION" android:value="42.0.0" />
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_RELEASE_CHANNEL" android:value="default" />

  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
      android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen"
    >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"/>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

3. If you're still having issues, remember that Android `versionCode` and `versionName` are two different things. Android does not seem to recognize [semver standards](https://semver.org/). `versionCode` increments as whole numbers (ie, if you went from semver `v1.0.0` to `v1.1.0` that is versionCode `1` to `2`.

Comment: Good explanation thanks, also I found this to do automatically every time you run a build: https://www.csestack.org/fixed-version-code-1-has-already-been-used-try-another-version-code-react-native-expo-error/

Answer (score 5):

There are two reason you got this issue in Play console.

**Case 1 -** You already had an app in Play Store and while updating new version of apk or abb in play console you got this issue.

**Solution For This :**  Go to file name pubspec.yaml it would look like this **version  : 1.0.0+1**
[image]

Here this **+1** is the version of your apk you need to update it to **+2** this is because play console need to reconize the new version of apk so each time you make any changes in your app and publish it again you need to update to **+1,+2,+3** .. so on.

Like This

[image]

**CASE 2 :**  You were about to publish another version in playstore you uploaded in play console but didnt fully Submit all your changes in play console. So the uploaded apk or abb goes on Play console draft  you need to remove it
for this

**Solution For Case 2 :**Play Console Dashboard and on Left side There is App Bundle Explorer or you can simply search App bundle Explorer

[image]
If you get **Delete app Bundle** here you can delete it as it will solve your problem.
[image]

If you didnt get it You can do this.

[image]

If you didnt get **Delete app bundle** button there you need to delete the draft from releases overview
on Left side there is **releases overview**

[image]

and go tot releases tab and d**iscard releases** the last history
[image]

If you **discard this release** the you will get **delete app bundle** button on **App Bundle Explorer**
[image]

*If it solves your problem **Glad to know** . Dont forget to upvote.*

Answer (score 2):

with my flutter project building a release for android i faced the same issue. all was doing is change version code in Pubspec.yaml but did not seem to change my android version...
so i went to Android folder and added version code manually in local.properties file :
`/project/android/local.properties`

`flutter.versionName=1.1.0`

`flutter.versionCode= from 1 to 4`

Comment: No! The local.properties files is regenerated and the 'flutter.xx' variables are generated (splitting on '+' char) from 'version:' items in pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 2):

Versioning works the other way around. Do not update the pubspec.yaml manually.

See the default comment in the pubspec.yaml:

```yaml
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
```

So you should run

```bash
flutter build appbundle --build-name 2.0.0 --build-number 2
```

This updates the pubspec.yaml for you.

Comment: It did not update pubspec.yaml for me

Comment: This....Claps!!!

Answer (score 2):

For the pre-release version, I solved this problem:
Create a new release in Production.
Choose **"Add from library"** where we upload apk. Then choose the same apk for testing.

Answer (score 2):

[image: local.properties]

for flutter change here in local properties  file

Answer (score 2):

**if it's second time publish app**

then increase your `version code` in android studio.

**if you already increased version code**

then it's already `saved` as a `draft`,
go to **release** section > **App Bundle Explorer** > select specified **version code** -> **delete** app bundle (top right).

now feel free to create another release

Answer (score 1):

I always used to increment version code in my `android/app/build.gradle` file, and it always used to work. Then, after a recent update in Android Studio, it suddenly didn't anymore, and I got this error!

I never cared to dig into the `build.gradle` code, but now, I did. Here, at the "TODO", is where I used to change the version code number:

```dart
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '19' // TODO: ---Count up with each release
}
```

But that only works if the version code from the `local.properties` file comes back as "null"!... I just realized. So probably, all this time, my compiler never managed to get values from local properties, but now all of a sudden, it does!

So I found the `android/local.properties` file and tried changing the version code there:

```dart
sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\karol\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk
flutter.sdk=C:\\src\\flutter
flutter.buildMode=release
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1   //Change this to 19 (my current version code number)
```

But that didn't work, because the moment I ran `flutter build appbundle`, this file changed itself back to the original values...

I then tried adding version code values to my `AndroidManifest.xml` file, according to serraosays' answer, but that didn't help me either.

### Functioning work-around

In the end, I did this in the `android/app/build.gradle` file:

```dart
def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
//if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '19' // TODO: ---Count up with each release
//}
```

That is, I commented out the condition. Now, my setting would over-write any value retrieved from the `local.properties` file.

If anyone can tell me the *proper* way to increment the version code number, I'm all ears!  But in the meantime, this worked for me, and hopefully for someone else as well.

Comment: Bro I got the same problem as you, Local properties value always reset or return as null.

I found out, caused by wrong path, the end with Sdk not sdk.

so check your : sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\karol\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk

Compare to your local path, whether it is exactly the same. Case sensitive.

Please lemme know if it solved.

Comment: Interesting... I'm not coding at the moment, but I'll look into it when I have a chance, and let you know! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you get the above error in the google play console, please change the `version:`  in `pubspec.yaml`.

Reference. [How to set build and version number of Flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54357468/how-to-set-build-and-version-number-of-flutter-app)

and me works [image]

Comment: and you need  `% flutter build appbundle --release` again

Comment: Weird that this works for you!... This has never worked for me. Also "version" and "version code" are not the same thing so... your SDK automatically increments your version code when you change your version name? 

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons for this error:

1. First, is common given in other answers: you must increase the version number to send an update to Play Console. Eg. previous app version: 1.0.5+5 and next update must contain 1.1.2+6. The +6 must be next to the previous update present on your play console.
2. Second reason for this error is you have skipped some numbers in between. Eg. Previous released version: 1.0.5+5 but the new version you are trying to release is 1.0.6+8. The +8 is not allowed directly, you must put +6 then +7 and then next numbers.

Answer (score 0):

In unreal engine you can change this in project settings. Steps are as follows.
(Me I'm using UE4.27.2)

1. Open Project Settings
2. Click all settings and in the top search bar type in "version" Without Quotes.
3. Scroll down to >Platforms>Android>apk packaging
4. Change the store Version for each +1 what you already have
   [APK PAckaging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwiaU.png)

(You do not need to change version display name but you can if you want to this can be edited later on in google console)

Answer (score 0):

change version code here please check the image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK1HB.png)

Answer (score 0):

For hybrid apps/JavaScript based frameworks like Ionic or Flutter updating `package.json` is not enough you sometimes, can directly edit `build.gradle` file in the **build folder**.

```
versionCode 2
versionName "2.0"
```

This is not a good practice

Answer (score 0):

So, the version codes are internal codes not displayed to the app users publicly. When we rebuild the app with a new version, we usually increment the version code by 1 every time.

Now, let's talk about deleting previous app bundles. If a bundle is attached to any of the tracks, Google doesn't allow deactivating or deleting that bundle. The option to do so is only available when the bundle is not attached to any track.

You can refer to this: [https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/thread/215317396/how-do-i-remove-an-app-bundle?hl=en#:~:text=You%20can%20remove%20a%20bundle,of%20the%20app%20on%20it](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/thread/215317396/how-do-i-remove-an-app-bundle?hl=en#:%7E:text=You%20can%20remove%20a%20bundle,of%20the%20app%20on%20it).

Keep in mind that you can change the version name or string to display it to users as you desire. For details on versioning, check out this: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is some confusion in other answers with respect to changing the version code from `version: 1.0.0+1` to `version: 1.0.0+2` in `pubspec.yaml` file.

The following comments in `pubspec.yaml` file will help you understand the version code and version name in android:

```
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
```

Therefore, if you have `version: 1.0.0+2`, it means your `versionName` is `1.0.0` and `versionCode` is `2`.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have already uploaded a bundle with the same version so you don't need to upload the same thing repeatedly. So in my case, I used `Add from library` instead of `upload` then I selected the bundle I uploaded already and Yay!! I'm good to go!!!

Answer (score 0):

For React Native:
Go to and open android>app>build.gradle

Change to higher number version.
versionCode 2
versionName "2.0"

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue and ultimately found a neat solution. I changed it in pubspec.yaml as follows:

```
version: 0.0.2+2
```

This gave me these number in local.properties:

```
flutter.versionName=0.0.2
flutter.versionCode=2
```

In fact pubspec.yaml describes it as follows:

```
# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
```

Answer (score -1):

For Flutter there are 2 locations where you need to change version number and version code.

1. In pubspec.yaml
   [image]
2. In android/app/build.gradle
   [image]

Let me know if there is any problem.

Comment: Were there meant to be some screenshots included with this answer?