# Cannot upload any new bundle on google play store (does nothing) after removing from the bundle explorer

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

I tried uploading an app bundle, it worked fine, but I wanted to check a few things and ended up with the error message "Version code 1 has already been used. Try another version code"

So I did what was written in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68058512/14027901
-> I removed the aab from the bundle explorer.

The problem is that now I cannot add any bundle anymore - when I go in "create new release" I cannot drag and drop, it does not do anything.

When I go back to "all apps" it says I have updated the app today although I have not validated anything.

Looks like something is unsync, how do I reinitialise the google play state?

(I have tried to log out and log in, and clear cache and it did not work)

Comment: Looks like a bug. Contact Play developer support.

Answer (score 0):

So the next day, I created a new bundle with an increased version number and it worked, google let me drag and drop it!