# Invalid version code when uploading xamarin app to Play Console

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I've created first application version for closed testing on Android Console with the version code set to `1` and version name to `1.0`. Now try to upgrade to version `2`/`2.0`. I've created an archive (Archive for Publishing in Visual Studio) and then signed the bundle. Visual Studio archive explorer shows my bundle with the version `2`/`2.0`. Bun when I try to upload in on the Play Console I get `Version code 1 has already been used. Try another version code.`. I even tried to raise the version to `3`/`3.0` but the message stays the same.

Any idea how to deal with it and where the problem is?

Comment: Please google using the title of your question. Examine the discussions found.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Version code 1 has already been used. Try another version code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68057944/version-code-1-has-already-been-used-try-another-version-code)

Comment: @DevenCC Not really. I think there might be some problem with Xamarin. I've found some issue that stated that output bundle ignores versions from config. So I decided to update packages (exactly I started to use .netstandard 2.1), built a packaged and it worked