# IPA not uploaded to App Distribution using fastlane

Tags: firebase, flutter, fastlane, firebase-app-distribution

I'm trying to upload IPA and APK files of a Flutter app to Firebase App Distribution using fastlane.

First time I deploy, both IPA and APK files were successfully uploaded to App Distribution. But after the first time, every time I deploy, the APK file is uploaded but the IPA is not uploaded, even though terminal shows that fastlane uploaded the IPA successfully.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

[image: android]

[image: iOS]

[image: terminal]

Answer (score 2):

Your releases might be grouped under the first release so it would not show on the Firebase Console.

Checkout this [comment](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution/issues/24#issuecomment-775499266) on an [issue](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution/issues/24) on the fastlane repo with an explanation:

> For background, App Distribution has a notion of releases and
> binaries. For iOS, we uniquely identify a release by its version
> information (CFBundleVersion, CFBundleShortVersionString) and a hash
> of just the app code. This hash excludes resource files such as the
> provisioning profile. A binary is uniquely identified by a hash of the
> IPA, including its resource files. For iOS ad-hoc distributions, it's
> common for releases to have multiple binaries associated with them
> since it's normal for developers to upload the same code with an
> updated provisioning profile to give testers access.
>
> In the Firebase Console, the cards you see are releases. So what may
> be happening is that you're uploading a build with no code changes. If
> this is the case, a new release won't be visible in the Firebase
> Console but the binary will be available for your testers to download.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that you've completed the steps in this answer to enable auto-versioning - https://stackoverflow.com/a/63914373/12806961.

In my case I had manually changed the iOS build number so even though I was passing a `--build-number` argument to the `flutter build ipa` command, it was using the old value when I uploaded to Firebase App Distribution.

I needed to update my info.plist to look like this:

```
<dict>
  ...
  <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
  <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
  <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
  <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
  ...
</dict>
```