# Firebase distribution require unique builds

Tags: firebase-app-distribution

I have setup firebase distribution with a Flutter app. I am noticing that android can receive app builds with the same build version number while iOS builds cannot.

Is there some way I can prevent this from happening in android in firebase distribution and have it require unique build as well?

Answer (score 0):

I ended using a script that sends incremented version to firebase:

It was possible to setup `pubspec.yaml` in such a way it syncs with the iOS and android app version and build version: [How to set build and version number of Flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54357468/how-to-set-build-and-version-number-of-flutter-app/63914373#63914373)

After that it's possible to setup a custom build script reading and incrementing version like given in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41955

This makes sure that version gets incremented

```
# Find and increment the version number.
perl -i -pe 's/^(version:\s+\d+\.\d+\.)(\d+)(\+)(\d+)$/$1.($2+1).$3.($4+1)/e' pubspec.yaml
```

...Coming from the GitHub thread

Answer (score 0):

You can use the --build-number argument in flutter build. In a GitHub action pass github.run_number for the build.

```
flutter build appbundle --flavor preprod --release --build-number $BUILD_NUMBER
```

When you upload to Firebase app distribution you will have the major version and then after it (build number).

Maybe not a perfect solution but it worked for me. I hope it can help you!