# Flutter app version in Android Studio differs from what I have in Xcode. How to solve this?

Tags: flutter, xcode, android-studio, version-control

I have a flutter project for my app, it is already released for IOS in AppStore and now I am trying to release it for Android in Google Play.
What confuses me that the version of the app that I see in Android Studio emulator (Nexus 6 API 28) shows a very old version of my app, while in XCode it is upated.

Does anyone know how to update Android version of the app according to what I have for IOS?

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/q/54357468/12349734 help?