# What is the purpose of the flutterVersionCode value in the build.gradle file?

Tags: flutter

For what purposes this value serves in the `android\app\build.gradle`?

```
def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `flutterVersionCode`, is the build number of your app.

Normally, this would be set from within your `pubspec.yaml`. For example, if you open the `pubspec.yaml` file, you'll see something like:

```
version: 1.0.0+1
```

where:

```
version: [version_number]+[build_number]
```

In your case, the `flutter.versionCode` corresponds to the `build_number` (the   `+1`).

**See also**

- [How to set build and version number of Flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54357468/12349734)

Comment: Does it mean that if we use in `pubspec.yaml` for instance `version: 1.2.5+8` then the so named `flutterVersionCode` will be filled automaticaly with the value `8`?

Comment: @rozerro that's correct