Is there a way to make the version and build number in macos/Runner.xcworkspace automatically match the version and build number from pubspec.yaml?
Is there a way to make the version and build number in macos/Runner.xcworkspace automatically match the version and build number from pubspec.yaml?

See my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74923857/12349734

They already did it by default, if you change version in pubspec.yml and re-build the project (by flutter tool/command, not by clicking play ▶️ button in XCode), it should automatically update Runner.xcworkspace

If not, maybe you need to double-check your Info.plist to make sure it was mapping like this

