# This release does not add or remove any APKs or App Bundles

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

In google play console app publish problem.
First time that i'm using google play for publish my app. Also shows app status: production, update status: in review. But not find at google play. Now should i do ?

[image: First time that i'm using google play for publish my app. Also shows app status: production, update status: in review. Now should i do ?]

[image: app status: production, update status: in review.]

Comment: Any update on your question?

Comment: I can't fix this issue, so that i re-upload my app. And this ok

Comment: Yes i did same thanks,

Comment: For the correct version update go to this other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53570575/flutter-upgrade-the-version-code-for-play-store

Comment: you shouldn't ask this question. google want to keep it unanswered

Answer (score 8):

step 1:

scroll down to release notes: .then add release as highlighted

[image]

step2:

add from library or upload a new one:
[image]

now continue publishing your release.

Comment: Sorted, thanks. Google are adding new complexities when releasing an app

Answer (score 1):

When I got this error I had previously deleted ("Discard release") an `.apk` that had been rejected for having errors. I then tried to replace it with an uploaded `.apk` with the same build number.

The solution was to increase the build number (`versionCode`). Note that the version (`versionName`) can stay the same.

Comment: Which file should these changes go into?

Comment: Probably `build.gradle`? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22274657/how-to-change-android-version-and-code-version-number)

Answer (score 0):

It says that the app is in review. Once review will be complete it will say Reviewed. Then you will be able to find it on Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

I also received this error.
First of all, I correctly set the time (my computer was not on time). Then, I built another version of the bundle and voila, no more error.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30180939)

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered this issue ,I found out I was not Entering Notes for App Bundle in Console.

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded the .aab first in production. Then I wanted to test the app and it gives an error. First you need to upload the app in test, then its works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

look into android/app/buildgradle
be sure this line is release like this

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using expo react native then you need to add

`"versionCode": 1.1,`

into

```
"android": {
"adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"        
      },
      "versionCode": 1.1,
      "package": "com.ijazalise.physicsolevel"
    },
```