# Google Play Console (French) : Build review error

Tags: google-play-console

I try to publish my first apps on google play store, after several days of research on google, I opened a case, but I'm not sure to have an answer one day...

Here, my situation :
I did many internal tests and created 6 releases to achieve a reliable and satisfactory application :

[Release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d49Y9.png)

When I launch the review of the release for production, I systematically have the following error (in french):

- Cette release ne permet pas d'ajouter ni de supprimer des app bundles.

In English :

- This release does not support adding or removing app bundles.

[My error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xroLK.png)

I don't understand the meaning of this error, and especially I don't know how to solve it.

Thank you for your help, Tchicken.

Comment: **Maybe this post helps:**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66270523/this-release-does-not-add-or-remove-any-apks-or-app-bundles